# Creating arrays dynamically using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hey folks, please lend a hand to a PHP beginner. I'm trying to put a load of dynamically created variabled into an array to re-read later, reason is a SOAP message sent is a mess and im trying to create a less complicated array:

```
$placea = "place a";
$placeb = "place b";

$myarray = array();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

what i want to be able to do:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [Place A] => Array
        (
            [0] => [Accommodation] => Array
                (
                    [RoomId] => 001
                    [RoomAvail] => true
                    [Date] => 12.04.2011

                )
            [1] => [Accommodation] => Array
                (
                    [RoomId] => 002
                    [RoomAvail] => true
                    [Date] => 12.04.2011

                )

        )    Array
(
    [1] => [Place B] => Array
        (
            [0] => [Accommodation] => Array
                (
                    [RoomId] => 101
                    [RoomAvail] => true
                    [Date] => 12.04.2011

                )
            [1] => [Accommodation] => Array
                (
                    [RoomId] => 102
                    [RoomAvail] => true
                    [Date] => 12.04.2011

                )

        )


)
```

how would i write that out in php? sorry if its bleek and/or the array structure is incorrect

Comment: what's the data look like that you want to go in the array?

Comment: do a var_dump(soap_response); to see the data

Comment: would love to, but its over 15000 lines. would grab a snippet. but an answer is given below. :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just need to use the `array` initializer repetitively.

If you want to initialize an array in PHP with some values, say 1 through 4, you make a call like:

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

And if you want to make an associative array, where you store some key/value pairs, you make a call like:

```
$foo = array('key' => 'value', 'other key' => 'other value');
```

But you can of course nest calls, and mix and match layers of associative and non associative arrays to achieve something like your example, e.g.:

```
$foo = array( 
    'Place A' => array( 
        // note use of first array on the next line is
        // to generate structure like [0] => 'Accomodation' => ...
        array('Accomodation' => array( 
            'RoomId' => '001', 
            'RoomAvail' => true, 
            'Date' => '12.04.2011')
        )), 
        array('Accomodation' => array( 
            'RoomId' => '002', 
            'RoomAvail' => true, 
            'Date' => '12.04.2011')
        ))
    ),
    'Place B' => array( 
        array('Accomodation' => array( 
            'RoomId' => '101', 
            'RoomAvail' => true, 
            'Date' => '12.04.2011')
        )), 
        array('Accomodation' => array( 
            'RoomId' => '102', 
            'RoomAvail' => true, 
            'Date' => '12.04.2011')
        ))
    )
);
```

This will very nearly produce what you're looking for, to make it replicate exactly what you have you would wrap each `'Place A'` with an `array` and each "place" would get its own assignment to some variable `$foo` (I assumed this wasn't actually what you wanted and wrote something maybe slightly more intuitive).

Comment: this is what im after. i just didn't know how to repeatidly add stuff to an array. I kept getting illegal offset and other offset errors when trying to give each place an numeric array id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a 'less complicated' array, you have a two arrays, one fore place a and one for place b and then merge them using array_merger() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php.

Study up on the array functions control structures in the manual. Many different ways of achieving bloated arrays uglying up your code.

Comment: agreed. the first array is mahoosive and data is all over the shop. im trying to set it into one array that i can keep in memory and get rid of the big one.

Answer (score 0):

This would dynamically create an array.

```
foreach($soapResponse as $key1 => $value1){
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
        // $key1 = Place A or B
        // value1 = array of values
        $arrayResponse[$key1][$key2] =  $value2;
    }
}
```